# External Files NOT skipped on debugging in VSCode (NodeJs)

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is driving me crazy. The VSCode debugger steps into code in node code despite apparently actually thinking it is skipped by skipFiles (which it should be)!

[image]

As you can see, it says `primordials.js` is skipped by skipFiles!! But the debugger is IN that file. Used to only for `async_hooks.js`, but now here also. It is maddening and makes debugging close to impossible.

What might I have done wrong? How can I fix this?

launch.json is

```
  {
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "debug-locally",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/services/index.js",
  "environment": [
    {
      "name": "OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY",
      "value": "YES"
    }
  ],
  "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
  "skipFiles": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
    "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
  ],
  "resolveSourceMapLocations": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
    "!**/node_modules/**"
  ]
},
```

Comment: Me too, I tried also `"<node_internals>/**"` but it doesn't work too.